# how to replace strings from content variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$content = "Please find the student results where Date of birth **BETWEEN** 2012-02-18 00:00:00 AND 2013-02-18 00:00:00  AND  name != "John" AND marks **BETWEEN** 40 AND 75 AND grade = 'A' AND AGE > 24"
```

I want to change bold strings with below strings

`BETWEEN` to  `IS BETWEEN`

`!=` to  `IS NOT EQUAL TO`

`=` to  `EQUAL TO`

`>` to `IS GREATER THAN`

means result like this:

Output: `"Please find the student results where Date of birth **IS BETWEEN** 2012-02-18 00:00:00 AND 2013-02-18 00:00:00  AND  name **IS NOT EQUAL TO** "John" AND marks **IS BETWEEN** 40 AND 75 AND grade **EQUAL TO** 'A' AND AGE **IS GREATER THAN** 24"`

Comment: I used this: $content.split("BETWEEN").join(" is between " ).split("=").join(" is equal to" );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
$content = $content
    .replace(/BETWEEN/g, "IS BETWEEN")
    .replace(/!=/g, "IS NOT EQUAL TO")
    .replace(/=/g, "IS EQUAL TO")
    ...
```

Note the use of the `g` flag in the regular expression to ask for the replacement of all occurrences.

---

Note that the order is important, as you don't want `=` to be replaced before `!=`. It's also possible to match `=` and not `!=` with `.replace(/([^!])=/g, '$1IS EQUAL TO')`.

Comment: It should be work simultaneously for each words. I tried this but next word is not replacing.

Comment: Did you try with the `g` flag as I specified ?

Comment: @dystory: It does matter sequence to replace string. Actually the content is coming dynamically and if '=' is first then it is not worked for same.

Comment: Yes, I know. But having `!=` before `=` is fine.